# event args array is not available in the transaction receipt

Tags: events, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to access the emitted events of a contract after calling a function. I wrote the following code.

```
const simpleNft = await ethers.getContract("SimpleNFT");

const mintTx = await simpleNft.mintNft();
const mintTxReceipt = await mintTx.wait(1);

console.log(mintTxReceipt);
const tokenId = mintTxReceipt.events[0].args.tokenId;
```

And naturally it throws an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at mintAndList (D:\Web3\nft-marketplace-backend\scripts\mint-and-list.js:12:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

When I checked the transaction receipt, there was no events array in the receipt and I don't understand why.
Please help me resolve the issue.

I tried googling the solution but all efforts in vain. I tried using a different method to call the contract in Hardhat. I used

`const simpleNft = await deployments.get("SimpleNFT");`

but when I use that I cannot call the function within the contracts. I can only call them when I use

`const simpleNft = await ethers.getContract("SimpleNFT");`

Comment: Hello, can you please share with us your package.json and the contract code you are interacting with?